# Does $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\sup_{t\in [-a,a]}|t|\cdot |f_{n}(t)|=0$ imply $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\sup_{t\in [-a,a]} |f_{n}(t)|=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

If we have $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\sup_{t\in [-a,a]}|t|\cdot |f_{n}(t)|=0$ can we get

$$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\sup_{t\in [-a,a]} |f_{n}(t)|=0.$$

In general I don't think so. Any counterexamples?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is no. Consider for instance $f_n(t)=e^{-n||t|}$. Then $f_n$ attains its maximum at $t=1/n$. Then for all $a>0$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{|t|\le a}|t|f_n(t)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{|t|\le a}\frac{1}{n\,e}=0,
$$
while
$$
f_n(0)=1\quad\forall n.
$$

Even $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$ is not enough. A sufficient condition is what I would call "uniform vanishing": for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist $n_\epsilon$ and $\delta_\epsilon>0$ such that
$$
n\ge n_\epsilon\text{ and }|x|\le\delta_\epsilon\implies|f_n(x)|\le\epsilon.
$$